# Checking and Unchecking a list of CheckBoxes

Tags: c#, checkbox

I have been able to check all the boxes in the list using the checkAll (a checkbox), but can't seem to uncheck them.

In the foreach, when I put in "industry.Checked = true", it checks all of them just fine. I want to also be able to uncheck them all, by unchecking the checkAll box.

```
    private void checkAll_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<CheckBox> industries = new List<CheckBox>();
        industries.Add(checkBasicIndustries);
        industries.Add(checkCapitalGoods);
        industries.Add(checkConsumerDurables);
        industries.Add(checkConsumerNonDur);
        industries.Add(checkConsumerServices);
        industries.Add(checkEnergy);
        industries.Add(checkFinance);
        industries.Add(checkHealthcare);
        industries.Add(checkMiscellaneous);
        industries.Add(checkPublicUtilities);
        industries.Add(checkTechnology);
        industries.Add(checkTransportation);

        foreach (CheckBox industry in industries)
        {
            if (industry.Checked = false)
            {
                industry.Checked = true;
            }

            else { industry.Checked = false; }

        }
    }
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Windows Form or Web Form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typo in

```
if (industry.Checked = false)    // Assignment operator
```

The single `=` assigns the value `false` to the `Checked` property.
So you set always all your CheckBoxes to false.

It should be

```
if (industry.Checked == false)   // Comparison operator
```

or just

```
if (!industry.Checked)
```

But better of all is (as suggested below by [Matthew Mcveigh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2685161/matthew-mcveigh))

```
foreach (CheckBox industry in industries)
    industry.Checked = !industry.Checked;
```

reducing your code to a single line

Comment: or just `industry.Checked = !industry.Checked;` and do away with the if